# Include export csv in highcharter

Tags: javascript, r, csv, highcharts, shiny

I'm trying to use this [link](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/35c2a73d7ff3e6db64c8cb03bb34f7cb2c53e42d/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/highcharts-5.0.5/plugins/export-csv.js) to get the export to csv button in `highcharter` but it's not working. Please find the relevant `highcharts` code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvD/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=cqjvD)

Thanks.
example:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "line") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Monthly Average Temperature") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Source: WorldClimate.com") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Temperature (C)")) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(line = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE),
    enableMouseTracking = FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  hc_series(
    list(
      name = "Tokyo",
      data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6)
    ),
    list(
      name = "London",
      data = c(3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8)
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled=T)
```

Comment: which version of highcharter are you using, your code with version `highcharter_0.4.0.9999` works fine

Comment: I think hes still on 0.3 as I see the same thing

Comment: I'm on 0.4.0. I'll update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at http://jkunst.com/highcharter/plugins.html#exporting-csv It was added in the development version, the release will be 0.5.0 in the couple of days.

```
hc <- highcharts_demo()

hc %>% 
  hc_exporting(
    enabled = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with the dev version just fine. But great that the new version will be on CRAN soon, our Shiny Server needs CRAN releases.....